# Undefined F1 scores in multiclass classifications when model does not predict one class

Tags: matlab, precision-recall, multiprecision, multiclass-classification

I am trying to use F1 scores for model selection in multiclass classification.

I am calculating them class-wise and average over them:
(F1(class1)+F1(class1)+F1(class1))/3 = F1(total)

However, in some cases I get NaN values for the F1 score. Here is an example:
Let true_label = [1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3] and pred_label = [2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3].

Then the confusion matrix looks like:
 C =[0 3 0; 0 3 0; 0 0 3]

Which means when I calculate the precision (to calculate the F1 score) for the first class, I obtain: 0/(0+0+0), which is not defined or NaN.

Firstly, am I making a mistake in calculating F1 scores or precisions here?
Secondly, how should I treat these cases in model selection? Ignore them or should I just set the F1 scores for this class to 0 (reducing the total F1 score for this model).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to avoid the division by zero for the precision in order to report meaningful results. You might find [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8025/what-are-correct-values-for-precision-and-recall-when-the-denominators-equal-0) useful, in which you explicitly report a poor outcome. Additionally, [this implementation](https://github.com/dice-group/gerbil/wiki/Precision,-Recall-and-F1-measure) suggests an alternate way to differentiate in your reporting between good and poor outcomes.